# Python turtle graphics using text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKQn8.png)I need help with Turtle graphics. I want the script to read my text file, and then draw a figure using the parameters in the text file. I think I almost got it, but gett error messages in the last part of the code.
Can somebody please help me, thank you! :)

```
import turtle
turtle.pensize(4)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(5)

with open ("tenge_eksempel_2.txt" , "r") as tekst:
lest_tekst = tekst.readlines()
Antall = 0
List_lengde = len(lest_tekst)
while List_lengde > Antall:
        if List_lengde < Antall:
        turtle.done()
    try:
        verdi = int(lest_tekst[Antall])
        if verdi < 0:
            turtle.penup()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.right(verdi)
        Antall = Antall+1
        verdi = int(lest_tekst[Antall])
        turtle.pendown()
        if verdi < 0:
            turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(verdi)
        Antall = Antall+1
        turtle.pendown()

turtle done
```

my text file looks like this:
black
15
200
lgihtgrey
150
200
etc...

Comment: Which error messages do you get?

Comment: The indentation is erroneous in the code. And the `try:` block needs to be followed by a `except:` block.

Comment: I suggest you fix the indentation first. Then I would add the missing `except:` block.

Comment: Uploaded a screenshot where you can see the error messages.

Comment: And please dont post screenshots showing code or error descriptions. Copy and paste it as text instead. That makes it possible to search for the error on SO. And possible for others to copy and try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this and see if it helps you figure out what's going on.

```
import turtle
turtle.pensize(4)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(5)

with open ("tenge_eksempel_2.txt" , "r") as tekst:
    temp = tekst.readlines()
lest_tekst = temp [0].split ()

Antall = 1
List_lengde = len(lest_tekst)
while List_lengde > Antall:
    verdi = int(lest_tekst[Antall])
    if verdi > 0:
        turtle.right(verdi)
        Antall = Antall+1
        verdi = int(lest_tekst[Antall])
        print (verdi)
    if verdi > 0:
        turtle.forward(verdi)
    Antall = Antall+2

turtle.done ()
```

tenge_eksempel_2.txt is :

```
black 15 200 lightgray 150 200 black 300 200 lightgray 150 200 black 300 200 lightgray 150 200 black 300 200 lightgray 150 200
```

**Edit:**
On my system I get :
[image]

Comment: It did open the Turtle Graphics window,  but the turtle didn't start. Just a white window. My text file looks like this: black
15
200
lightgray
150
200
black
300
200
lightgray
150
200
black
300
200
lightgray
150
200
black
300
200
lightgray
150
200

Comment: This answer needs some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Given the text above: black 15 200 lightgray 150 200 black 300 200 lightgray 150 200 black 300 200 lightgray 150 200 black 300 200 lightgray 150 200 .
Assuming the black and gray are turtle pen colors and the 1st number angle and the 2nd pen motion, How would you separate the color(string) from the number? I tried the above code from the accepted answer but got no drawing in python turtle graphics. Just an empty blank turtle window.

Edit: I got no error messages, nor do I get a message saying process completed. I even left it to run for like 15-20 minutes just in case it was just slow.